# How to instantiate ResourceResponse<Document>

Tags: c#, moq, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to mock a call that returns `ResourceResponse<Document>`, but I am not able to instantiate that type. Is there a factory class that can instantiate it or some other way to do so?

**EDIT**

`var response = new ResourceResponse<Document>();`

> The type 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.ResourceResponse' has no constructors defined

Comment: Define "not able". Your question is not specific to this class. Do you mean it's sealed and has got a private, protected or internal constructor? Then search on that. Anyway exposing a client library for a web service with only sealed classes is a bit idiotic, blame Microsoft.

Comment: Yes, it's a [sealed class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn799209.aspx)

Comment: Is there a factory class that instantiates it?

Comment: I'd probably take a step back and ask if you really need to be passing around a `ResourceResponse<T>` anyway? Perhaps you only need to mock your local objects rather than MS bits?

Comment: @DavidG yes, that was going to be the next step if there was no way to get an instance of the `ResourceResponse`.

Comment: @JonasStawski Did you finally get any solution for this? I landed up exactly in the same situation and I think any direction on this will help me immensely.

Comment: @tyrion if still usefull to you, I posted an answer a while back

Comment: Is there anyone who can generate MS Fakes for DocumentDbClient library?

Answer (score 7):

The latest stable version of Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB (1.10.0) atm added 2 constructors for mocking purposes.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn799209.aspx#Anchor_2

*Edit*

Using Moq you could do something like this:

```
Mock<IDocumentClient> documentClient = new Mock<IDocumentClient>();
documentClient
    .Setup(dc => dc.ReplaceDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri("database", "collection", "id"), object, null) // last parameter are RequestOptions, these are null by default
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(new ResourceResponse<Document>()));
```

This way I can check if the method on my documentClient is being called, if you want to influence what is returned in the document, you have to create a document, and following that a ResourceResponse of that document. Something like:

```
var document = new Document();
document.LoadFrom(jsonReader); // the json reader should contain the json of the document you want to return
Mock<IDocumentClient> documentClient = new Mock<IDocumentClient>();
documentClient
    .Setup(dc => dc.ReplaceDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri("database", "collection", "id"), object, null) // last parameter are RequestOptions, these are null by default
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(new ResourceResponse<Document>(document)));
```

Comment: Interesting, but not entirely helpful because the DocumentDB APIs return "ResourceResponse<Document>" - and hence, there's no way to leverage the methods that you referenced. Ideally, I wish they were returning something like IResourceResponse<IDocument>.

Comment: Well, an interface would indeed be ideal. But you can instantiate a ResourceResponse<Document>-object and use that as the response of a mocked call of DocumentClient. You say in your question that you cannot do `new ResourceResponse<Document>()` but with the update you can. I'll edit my answer with an example.

Comment: If you like an example of initializing the jsonreader, I could whip one up.

Comment: This really bothers me. Why they just cant use interfaces as return types when the interfaces are already there? I need to mock a result of `ResourceResponse` aka `.StatusCode` property. Cant do that, because the `StatusCode` is not `virtual` (bye bye NSubstitute) plus the `IDocumentClient` do not return interfaces at all:  (`Task<ResourceResponse<Attachment>> CreateAttachmentAsync(...)`)

Comment: But you can instantiate ResourceResponse

Comment: you can instantiate `ResourceResponse`, but you can't change the `.StatusCode` property (or any other properties), since it has only a getter. it always throws an `NullReferenceException` when the code tries to access it.

Comment: I made an issue for thin on GitHub: https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues/393

Comment: @YentheO, hoping you can show how to initialize the jsonReader please??

Comment: Something like:
var stringReader = new StringReader(documentJson);
var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader);
document.LoadFrom(jsonReader);

Answer (score 1):

The `ResourceResponse class` has the constructor that contains the DocumentServiceResponse parameter marked as internal.

This is bad because even though you can create a `ResourceReponse` object from your `DTO class` you cannot set things like RUs consumed, response code and pretty much anything else because they are all coming from the ResourceResponseBase which also has the DocumentServiceResponse marked as internal.

Please find code at below link

[how-to-mock-or-instantiate](https://answersadda.blogspot.com/2019/11/how-to-mock-or-instantiate.html)

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late but with Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core 2.4.2 there's a `DocumentClient` constructor that accepts an `HttpMessageHandler` as a parameter.  It's ugly (so much so it deserves a downvote) but you can use this to inject responses with status codes.  As far as I can tell nothing's leaving my box when I do this.

I also had to create a test-only constructor since I would never want to use this during running code.  But for anyone still interested until a better library comes out here are the relevant parts.

Create your client

```
var client = new DocumentClient(host, authText, handler);
```

In your tests you can use a mocked handler like this:

```
    public static Mock<HttpMessageHandler> CreateHttpMessageHandler(List<HttpResponseMessage> responses)
        {
            var handlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);
            handlerMock.Protected()
                .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
                nameof(HttpClient.SendAsync),
                ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(),
                ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
                .ReturnsAsync(() => {
                    var response = responses[0];
                    responses.RemoveAt(0);
                    return response;
                })
                .Verifiable();

            return handlerMock;
        }
```

I created this response factory simulator

```
    private HttpResponseMessage Respond(string text)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = new StringContent(text),
        };

        return response;
    }
```

and set up the handler with something like this:

```
        var responses = new List<HttpResponseMessage> {
           Respond("{ ... }"),
           Respond("{ ... }"),
           Respond("{ ... }"),
           Respond("{ ... }"),
        };
```

Replace the `...` with your Fiddler (or similar) trace output from an actual call to your CosmosDB.  FWIW I had to supply 2 copies of my actual payload as the final 2 responses.  This is obviously AS-IS and SUBJECT TO CHANGE but `It worked for me`.  Hope it helps you and looking forward to a modern library designed to interfaces with SOLID principles.